# Website log in not working on webview android

Tags: android, authentication, webview

I am currently developing a simple web browser application, and it works as a normal android web browser. but the problem is, When I'm trying to log in on some other website such as google mail,facebook and any other site that requires logging in features.Its just always refreshing after I log in and always returning to its homepage and nothing happens. Any Tips and suggestions?

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.webdyci);
    browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(webdycian.this);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();

    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


     //laman ng fieldtext
    lamanses = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String laman = intent.getStringExtra("fname");
    lamanses.setText(laman);
    ////
    browser.loadUrl(intent.getExtras().getString("fname")); 



String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.1; en-US; GT-P7500                   
    Build/HMJ37) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0  DesktopSafari/534.13";
    browser.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);
    browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        browser.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);



    browser.requestFocusFromTouch();
        browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);




    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I noted couple of issues in your code. Please do the changes like mentioned below and check. It should work.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);       
 setContentView(R.layout.webdyci); // initialization of the components should always be after setContentView();
        lamanses = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
        browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);



        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(webdycian.this);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();

        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


         //laman ng fieldtext
        and then rest of the code as it is.
```

Please re-run and Let us know...

Comment: sir I've used the code that you made. and the application just force closed upon opening the browser.

Comment: Please re-post your latest code along with the Logcat error you see.

Comment: Also do you've "   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />" entered in your manifest file ?

Comment: @ramakishma balla ive declared the Internet permission on android manifest.

Answer (score 0):

In LogCat it is clearly mentioned as

`"Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content"`

Please use it before setContentView().....like in my below code.

Comment: Still no luck at all.

Comment: there's no force close issue but the log in issue is still not solved.